# Internet explorer refresh is not happening on press of enter key in url bar

Tags: web-applications, browser, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

Recently I found a small problem in IE. In ie7 browser whenever I press enter(return) key in url bar it refreshes the current page. But same behavior is not happening if the url contains "#" token. We use the "#" token for javascript history support. If we remove the "#" token it works well. Is this the issue with ie7 or it is the expected behaviour? I tested with other browser like firefox and chrome. Seems to be only in IE7 it happens. When we press enter we get the feeling like browser is refreshing. But really not. 
[image]

Any ideas?!!

Comment: Can you retrain your users to use the control+R refresh key binding instead? Might as well teach them something that works on most browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It is a design decision on the part of Microsoft, so is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior, and what I'm experiencing in FF4 right now.

It's similar to the behavior of clicking [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816369/internet-explorer-refresh-is-not-happening-on-press-of-enter-key-in-url-bar/5816398#)

It's very unlikely that any user is going to do this, and in IE7. I would not worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks.Most of the users are having the habit of pressing enter in the url bar and expecting the refresh to happen in the page. This happens only if I support javascript history. They should have restricted to all the url's.

Comment: That is unusual behavior, for a computer-illiterate or an expert.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the # will navigate the site an an anchor.  stands for anchor. So if you have a document with sections 1,2 and 3, you can can send them there using the link: `example.com/index.html#section3`.

Pages where this logic is used very well are ones like Gmail. Open up Gmail and watch the userbar. You'll notice you're not reloading the page, you're just clicking links and buttons and the page is changing. The Hashtag can be read and provide links in case you'd like to return to that page in the future. The future of the web is being made with web applications where you don't have to navigate to a completely different page, the page only loads what is needed. This is an extremely simplified example of a page where it keeps track of your navigation inside the URL bar.

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-jquery-ui-tabs/#some_tabs=3

I know it's weird that users can't reload the page by hitting enter if there is a "#", but that will never be never be the case. Embrace the future.